# Ionic5 set item color at runtime

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic5

I am trying to achieve the same ionic3 behavior in my ionic5 project.
My item background color shall be determined at runtime based on a variable

Ionic3 HTML:

```
<ion-item [ngStyle]="{'background-color': color, 'color':'#363232'}">
```

Where `color=rgb(255,51,0)` or similar. Works in ionic3. Now, what is the ionic5 syntax to enable this?

Thanks, El

Answer (score 1):

Use **--ion-background-color** instead of background-color.

In html

```
  <ion-item style="--ion-background-color: {{_bckgndclr}}; color: #363232;">
```

In ts

```
_bckgndclr: any = 'rgb(255,51,0)';
```

You can change the color, by changing the **_bckgndclr** variable in ts.

Thank you.

Comment: Does unfortunately not work, even if I set it to a constant value: `style="--ion-background-color: #00FF00; color:#363232;"`